# Spin Button for excel

Tags: excel, button

I am trying to add a spin button to increment a value where ever the data is present.

I manually added a spin button for one field to increment the value. How can add spin buttons where ever a the value is present. Something like shopping cart.

```
Private Sub quantity_SpinDown()
   Range("M6").Value = Range("M6") - 1

End Sub

Private Sub quantity_SpinUp()
Range("M6").Value = Range("M6") + 1

End Sub
```

I am expecting this spin button where ever there is an item in cart is present to increment the value of the item in the cart.[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGj76.png)

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro to dynamically create spinners. In the example bellow you can select some cells in your worksheet and then execute the following `Sub`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub createSpinnersInSelection()

    Dim spinner As OLEObject
    Dim selectedCell As Range

    For Each selectedCell In Selection
        ' Creates a spinner
        Set spinner = selectedCell.Parent.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.SpinButton.1", Top:=selectedCell.Top, Left:=selectedCell.Left, Height:=selectedCell.RowHeight, Width:=15)

        ' Setting spinner properties
        With spinner
            ' Cell to change the value
            .LinkedCell = selectedCell.Address(0, 0)
            With .Object
                ' Initial value
                .Value = 0
                ' Increment of cell
                .SmallChange = 1
            End With
        End With
    Next selectedCell

End Sub
```

You may add more properties such as spinner color and others (the code was adapted from this [thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1069905-vba-code-creating-spin-button-range-cells.html))

**Important note:** You may need to tweak a little bit the `.LinkedCell` value since when you filter the columns it may keep the original cell reference, changed the value in a different cell than the expected one.